# NSTextView: Resign First Responder in storyboard app

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, becomefirstresponder

I have a macOS app using storyboards (OSX 10.12; Xcode 9). The view controller I am interested in is embedded in a SplitViewController which is embedded in a SplitViewController which is the main ViewController's contentViewController, so it's sitting three levels deep.

In this view controller, I have an NSTextField ("title") and an NSTextView ("body"). Whatever I do, the NSTextView is the first responder, and I want my NSTextField to be the first item the user types into.

I have tried using  NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.makeFirstResponder(title)
in ViewWillAppear (mainWindow is still nil in ViewDidLoad; thanks, Storyboard) but it has no effect whatsoever: after calling this, body remains the first responder.

Using body.resignFirstResponder() or title.becomeFirstResponder() equally have no effect at all (I know the documentation says "Never invoke this method directly", but it had to be tried); the cursor continues to blink happily inside the text view.

I've managed to create a hack by subclassing NSTextView, initially returning false from 'acceptsFirstResponder' and setting it back to 'true' in the viewDidLoad method of my ViewController, but that's ugly and simply sidesteps the responder chain.

What's the correct way of setting my NSTextField as first responder when the NSTextView just does not want to take the hint?

Comment: Is the NSTextField above the NSTextView? Do you do anything to them, setting the contents, a binding or something? Did you try setting `initialFirstResponder` of the window?

Comment: The TextField is above and to the left of the TextView, this makes no difference whatsoever. I'm setting the contents in ViewDidLoad; I have just reversed the order, but that makes no difference. initialFirstResponder is an interesting one - I hadn't known about that. I've set it in ViewWillAppear (which seems to be the first place I can access the window), and while it will tell me in the console that my textField is the initial first responder, the cursor blinks happily in the textView.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it must be something you do somewhere somehow.

Comment: I've now played a bit more with this, and I may have blamed NSTextView when the issue is elsewhere: if I add two NSTextFields to a ViewController in a storyboard, the one that got added first is first responder, whatever I do.

Comment: This seems to be a timing thing - if I add this code in the window controller, and set initialFirstResponder in windowDidLoad, it works fine. But see above re: 'three levels deep in storyboards' and I'm obviously missing _something_.

Comment: Try switching on Recalculates View Loop of the window, maybe it helps.

Comment: I've found the root cause of the problem - window.isRestorable (see answer below) - so it's probably best not to fight this behaviour. Thank you for your help in working this out!

Comment: That's why I couldn't reproduce it, I switched window restoration off in the system prefs.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem with all of my attempts to set the first responder is that I did absolutely nothing wrong: NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.makeFirstResponder(title) called inside ViewWillLoad appears to be exactly the method that is needed called at exactly the right time.

That is, unless the window is set to 'restorable' which in Xcode 8/9 is the default setting. (This confuses me somewhat. The documentation says "If you mark your windows as restorable, you must associate a restoration class with them."; this is not set by default, and it's a little more complicated than it sounds at first. (see https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial for an iOS tutorial; I will see how much of it applies to macOS).)

One of the things that *does* get preserved between launches, other than window position and size, is which interface element was active when you quit the application; with window.isRestorable set to false, initialFirstResponder works as advertised.

This is a slightly unsatisfying answer, but it sounds like one of these 'intended behaviour' problems, so I might just have to live with being completely unable to determine which text element is active on launch. (I can see use cases either way, but window restoration has enough advantages that I'm likely to adopt it.)